# Shell script can't be run in cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin

I have a script as below:

```
# /brickos/util/f.sh
set folder=`pwd`
cd /brickos/boot
make
firmdl3 -f brickOS.srec
cd $folder
```

when I run it in cygwin(minty.exe), I got error as below, but when I run them in terminal directly, no any errors! what can I do?

```
$ f.sh
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/brickos/util/f.sh: line 2: cd: /brickos/boot
: No such file or directory
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/brickos/util/f.sh: line 3: $'make\r': command not found
firmdl3: ERROR- failed to open brickOS.srec
/cygdrive/c/cygwin/brickos/util/f.sh: line 5: cd: 
: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I believe it's just a problem of trailing `\r`'s in your script (just use your editor to disable that feature: use `UNIX/Linux newlines` or something such, in the preferences of your editor).

Comment: Otherwise your scripting style is terrible: you should perform checkings after each command, so as to not have a wild-running script that does unwanted stuff in unwanted places. And don't use backticks! And use more quotes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$'make\r': command not found
```

suggests the script is saved with Windows (CRLF) instead of Unix style (just LF) line endings. Try converting it to Unix format and see if that improves matters.

Comment: This is obviously the reason (see my comment in the OP).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf indeed, I saw your comment after I'd posted my answer. If you want to turn your comment into an answer I'll delete this one.

Comment: No problem let's leave like this `:)`